# Flatlist Image source in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render a `FlatList` in React Native that it will be like an image carousel.

I want to provide the image sources in the assets folder and pass each items source in the renderItem but i get error undefined is not an object.

Here is the state:

```
export default function App() {
  const [images, setimages] = useState([
    {src:require('./assets/image1.png'),key:'1'},
    {src:require('./assets/image2.png'),key:'2'},
    {src:require('./assets/image3.png'),key:'3'},
    {src:require('./assets/image4.png'),key:'4'},
    {src:require('./assets/image5.png'),key:'5'}
  ]);
```

And here is the `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
  horizontal={true} 
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
  data={images}
  renderItem={ ({images}) => (
    <Image source={images.src} style={{
      width:260,
      height:300,
      borderWidth:2,
      borderColor:'#d35647',
      resizeMode:'contain',
      margin:8
    }}></Image>
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

React Native `FlatList` [`renderItem`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) callback get an object parameter with 3 props, `item`, `index` and `separators`:

> ### [**`renderItem`**](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem)
>
> ```
> renderItem({item, index, separators});
> ```

You don't have to define keys in your array, just the images sources and then use `item` and `index` inside your `renderItem` function:

#### Define just an array with the sources:

```jsx
const [images, setimages] = useState([
  require('./assets/image1.png'),
  require('./assets/image2.png'),
  require('./assets/image3.png'),
  require('./assets/image4.png'),
  require('./assets/image5.png')
]);
```

#### And use `item` and `index` for `source` and `key`:

```jsx
return (
  <FlatList
    horizontal={true} 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
    data={images}
    renderItem={ ({ item, index }) => (
      <Image source={item} /* Use item to set the image source */
        key={index} /* Important to set a key for list items,
                       but it's wrong to use indexes as keys, see below */
        style={{
          width:260,
          height:300,
          borderWidth:2,
          borderColor:'#d35647',
          resizeMode:'contain',
          margin:8
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

**UPDATE**

We should never use indexes for JSX keys because on a rearrangement or the array, we'll end up with the same indexes pointing to different items.

There is an ESLint rule regarding that issue [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md):

> [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md)
>
> #### Prevent usage of Array index in keys (react/no-array-index-key)
>
> Warn if an element uses an Array index in its `key`.
>
> The `key` is used by React to [identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed and should be stable](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).
>
> It's a bad idea to use the array index since it doesn't uniquely identify your elements. In cases where the array is sorted or an element is added to the beginning of the array, the index will be changed even though the element representing that index may be the same. This results in unnecessary renders.

We should create unique keys for each item (*and maybe store them inside our images array if we have a large items count*) by using some fast hashing algorithms like [CRC32](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crc32) on the image name or by using [`nanoid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) to generate a random key for each image.

Comment: keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} remove VirtualizedList: missing keys for items...

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're trying to destructure a `images` parameter which doesn't exist, it's called `item`.

Try this instead:

```js
return (
    <FlatList 
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={images}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Image 
                source={item.src}
                style={{
                    width:260,
                    height:300,
                    borderWidth:2,
                    borderColor:'#d35647',
                    resizeMode:'contain',
                    margin:8
                }}
            />
        )}
    />
);
```

Comment: Dont work: error->invalid prop source (i can see images url in log)

Answer (score 1):

the comment above is correct, however there is the `uri` attribute inside the source where you assign the url of the image see:

```
return (
    <FlatList 
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={images}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Image 
                source={{ uri: item.src }}
                style={{
                    width:260,
                    height:300,
                    borderWidth:2,
                    borderColor:'#d35647',
                    resizeMode:'contain',
                    margin:8
                }}
            />
        )}
    />
);
```

Comment: passing uri path worked fine

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Image} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'





const CarScreen = () => {

  const data=[
    {src:require("./assets/car1.jpg")},
    {src:require("./assets/car2.jpg")},
    {src:require("./assets/car2.jpg")},
  ]
    
  



  const onRenderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (

      <View>
        
        
        
        <Image source={item.src} style={{
          width: 260,
          height: 300,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: '#d35647',
          resizeMode: 'contain',
          margin: 8
        }}></Image>

      </View>



    )
  }


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={onRenderItem}
        horizontal
        />


    </View>
  )
}

export default CarScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).